# Different alert message for each select <option> using PayPal form?

Tags: javascript, paypal

My PayPal form has three different options.

I've successfully added an alert popup message when you click on any of the three options, and it displays the same popup for each of the three.

Is there a way to create a different popup message for each of the three options?

Here's my [webpage](http://www.cbdhempoildiscounts.com/real_scientific_hemp_oil.htm).

You'll find corresponding code on:

Lines 64-66:

```
function FP_popUpMsg(msg) {//v1.0
    alert(msg);
}
```

Lines 243-248:

```
<select name="os0" onchange="FP_popUpMsg('bla bla bla')">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="1 - 3 gm RSHO Tube">1 ea. 3 Gram 21% RSHO Tube $179.00</option>
<option value="1 - 10 gm RSHO Tube, 1 Brain Dart, 1 Atomizer, 1 Triple Threat">1 ea. 10 Gram 21% RSHO Tube $549.00</option>
<option value="6 - 10 gm RSHO Tubes, 2 Brain Dart, 2 Atomizer, 2 Triple Threat">6 ea. 10 Gram 21% RSHO Tubes $2,499.00</option> 
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the `FP_popUpMsg` method without any parameters and also add an id to your `select` element:

```
<select name="os0" id="myDropDownBox" onchange="FP_popUpMsg();"...
```

Then change your method signature and body as follows:

```
function FP_popUpMsg() {
    switch( document.getElementById("myDropDownBox").selectedIndex )
    {
        case 0:
            alert("your message for option 1");
            break;
        case 1:
            alert("your message for option 2");
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("your message for option 3");
            break;
    }
}
```

Please adjust according to your needs.